# Session expired error immediately after logging in using Selenium Chrome WebDriver in Python

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to login to the webpage below and my code is able to do that for me with no errors. But the moment the code hits the "Login" button, the following error message appears:
[image]

how do I resolve this? I am using a Chrome Browser with Selenium in python to automate this process. I am getting the same error while using the edge browser as well.

I am using the following code to achieve this:

```
chrome_driver_path = r"C:\Users\selenium\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe"
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=chrome_driver_path,options=options)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 5)
#open the webpage and enter the email id on the login page
driver.get("https://auth.slido.com/login? auth_state=eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCIsImtpZCI6IkIifQ.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.Y7WjeXgVCoZMKTfbJ2iy-O7UQn8_-vz_ZhgwsyuyrxervrMnBRYN-oCGEnRI5SnQDlRxif1qBSpDUxNSOOGnv4wgCTLRfq-X-AE7dHeOFcvAdGmmCl_HGGEpQ5plA7yT7f7pMt6xibK2ZhwNL7KwY_OUgVpgz0ROcSv7wBQVNGcx2Am0NfGZw1eDEhBfyiUTktGqTDVyQfmNAB3F7G7PtvgoXEikLLTZBqBY93d5w4RrjxIt6tzdiNpBKwwMulXmSzr0OGnLiRCQXsNfLyst028Hmoq_HsxFLICTKxZTOkelFB83XM1zGRnUkjCOCT-EhQbT0I-hJvQccdlbCdjXKg")

#first accepting all cookies before moving to our actual search
driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"/html/body/div[2]/div[2]/button[2]").click()
time.sleep(2)
#assigining the username
driver.find_element(By.ID,"email").send_keys("xyz@abc.com")
#then clicking on the continue button and move forward
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "/html/body/auth-root/auth-layout/div[3]/div/auth-login/div/div/form/auth-recaptcha/div/div[2]/button").click() 
time.sleep(2)
#now we need to assing the password to login
driver.find_element(By.ID,"password").send_keys("####")
#click on the login button next
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "/html/body/auth-root/auth-layout/div[3]/div/auth- login/div/div/form/auth-recaptcha/div/div[2]/button").click()
time.sleep(2)
print("Logged in")
```

Comment: Did you try using an already logged in chrome profile (created in the normal chrome browser)?

Comment: I tried that as well. but it didn't seem to work but essentially if I re-login after clicking the expired session button it works fine for me

Comment: Ok, also did you try undetected chromedriver?

Comment: I didn't. How can I do that?

Comment: First install with `pip install undetected-chromedriver` then import with `import undetected_chromedriver as uc` and open browser with `driver = uc.Chrome()`